# Creating Binary Files to upload app in app store

Tags: iphone, xcode4.3, binaryfiles

I want to create a Binary file of my project. I have set my project to iPhoneDistribution mode. After that I build the project(command B), now, in Xcode in left panel under project , clicking on .app it should reveal the path. But .app is showing that path.

A few days back, I have tried to create binary file of the same project that time it has worked. After that I have renamed the project. Now, I think due to this only, m not getting my result.

So, how will I get the binary file, any Suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use "Archive" to make a release build? That's the recommended way and makes things much easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 ways to submit your app to the App Store.

1. Archive your project and submit using the Distribute button in Xcode.
2. Zip your .app file and submit using the Application Loader app from Apple.

I believe that the suggested way to submit is number 1. There are plenty of tutorials and answers on SO how to perform either of these.

I can tell you renaming stuff in your project usually leads to pain in the ass problems with submission. If it gets bad, I would consider renaming it back if you can help it. Otherwise when you perform validation for submission, it should tell you which setting is in conflict and you can resolve it at that time. You can perform validation on the build in the Archive tab of Organizer. Archive, Validate, Distribute are the keys to successful submission. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

just get in to the build folder inside your project,there you can see your project,because of you changes the name of the project the build should be in the new name.thats why it is not showing in the finder.